# Making group in django app.

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am making an app. In which multiple superusers are there and beneath these super user we have multiple user. I am able to make superuser.But I am not able to add user in that for that super user.I am relatively new in django.

Comment: I understand you want to introduce a user hierarchy where a superuser "contains" a set of regular users?

Comment: yes,The super user contain a set of user which can use all the filed or I can say when they log in with there username , they link to superuser account and work on all the superuser field.

Comment: You may need to extend the `User` class with a foreign key to the "parent" user (the superuser which contains the current user).

Answer (score 1):

Superusers are special as their permission system returns True on every permission request (it is hardcoded). There is no "super group". You can simply create a group and give it all permissions (so add, change and delete permission to every model).